# How can I put on contact lenses without a mirror?

Tags: eyesight, contact-lenses

I sometimes wear soft contact lenses, and I always have to be in front of a mirror to put them in.  Being in front of a mirror lets me see the lens on my finger and I can watch the lens as my finger approaches my eye.  I can see where the lens is when I put it on my eye, and then I know how to move my eye around in case it's not perfectly centered.  I can also blink a few times and then see if the lens is still in place.

I have never been able to put the lenses in without a mirror.  Without a mirror I can't tell how the lens is seated on my eye.  If I blink, sometimes the lens falls out.

How can I put in my contact lenses without a mirror?

Comment: Do you have a smart phone with a camera on it? Could that somehow be used?

Comment: Mirrors are everywhere. Cars have two suck on the outside for anybody to use. Just go outside to the street (or fill the sink with water!)

Comment: It's easier to find a mirror-like object like sunglasses or a black cellphone screen.

Comment: Not a hack, but an alternative solution to the problem:buy yourself a small mirror with suction cups on the back - they're usually magnifying by 10x. Keep it with you and you can stick it on any vertical surface while you do the lenses. Not so easy if you're a guy I'm guessing though: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Small-Swissco-Mirror-Magnifying-Suction/dp/B000XXX736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried searching for solution on how to do this? Like [how to put on contacts without mirror](//google.com/search?q=how+to+put+on+contacts+without+a+mirror). The general consensus with small variations on which fingers to use are as follows:

- Clean your hands before starting
- Use the left hand, if right handed, to lift the upper part of the eye lid
- Place contact on right middle finger. Do make sure that it is the correct way
- Use either right index (or ring) finger (or both) to pull down on skin below eye
- Look up with eyes only. Can be easier if you tilt chin a little down
- Place contact on eye in a steady motion, and move slightly around till it sits in right position
- Let go of skin around eye, start with right hand, and then left hand
- Glance around, blink, make sure the contact is correctly seated
- If not, take it out again and repeat from top
- If it is good, repeat for the other eye

Do train a few times for this at home in front of mirror, so that you don't do this for the first time when away from the mirror. Also keep a towel or some cover underneath in the start in case you drop the contact.

Take care of hygiene whenever handling contacts, both when inserting or removing them.

Answer (score -1):

Use a knife with a flat polished blade.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. I'm not sure how feasible this answer is. Using a knife might be a little too small to see clearly. Is there any way to make it seem bigger and clearer?

Comment: I successfully used an el-cheapo kitchen Tramontina chef knife today to put on my contact lenses. Not sure if something bigger is really needed, but if it is, a polished kitchen hatchet might be used I guess

Comment: just add this comment to the answer above

Comment: Would you please add a detailed description of how you use a knife while placing the contact in your eye.  While I can infer that you are using the knife as a mirror, your answer does not convey that intention.